# How to tell if a frame is a KEY frame in RTMP stream

Tags: rtmp, tcpdump

I use a third party server that emits RTMP stream but I don't have full control over that server.

However, I can still make it emit a rtmp stream to any location of my choice.

I was told by the third party that the key frame rate they are emitting is at least 1 per second. But i just want to verify that myself

I tried to use tcpdump to inspect my incoming RTMP stream.

But I wonder how i can tell if a packet contains a keyframe? And how do I tell the frequency at which the key frames are arriving to my server?

Comment: look at the frame type value in the flv tag header.

Comment: How do I do that? @szatmary. Is there a tool for me to do it? My server is on aws. What should I install to listen to 1935 port and inspect the incoming stream?

Comment: When you did your research on the problem, what options looked like they would work in your environment?

Comment: There are currently no tools available to do that I think. tcpdump is the only thing feasible. But that requires me to have extensive knowledge on the low level of RTMP.

Comment: There are no tools? Does rtmpdump not count? If not, than you may need to obtain that TCP/RTMP knowledge to create a tool.

Comment: Do you happen to know what I need to run with rtmpdump to get the key frame interval? That is the essence of my question....

Comment: You should always assume it to be variable. But If thats what you want ffprobe is a better option. If you have more questions, please start a new post.

Comment: @szatmary I use a third party server that emits RTMP stream. I don't have full control over that server. I can only make it emit a rtmp stream to any location of my choice. Can I actually use ffprobe or rtmpdump to receive the rtmp stream and inspect? I can't find any doc for these things to do that. If they can, do you know what I need to do? I was told by the third party that the key frame rate they are emitting is at least 1 per second. But i just want to verify that myself.

Comment: Just set up an rtmp server

Comment: Well that is what I am asking. What tool can I use to receive an RTMP stream and inspect? I know i need an "rtmp" server. But how do I do that?

Comment: you should google "rtmp server" and click the first link.

Comment: From what I understand, the nginx solution accepts a rtmp stream and basically redirect it to other people when people subscribe to it. But it doesn't offer any solution in inspecting what the stream actually is. Or what the key frame interval is. Do you have a solution in mind, or are you just randomly googling stuff like I have been doing this whole morning =/

Comment: Once you receive the stream with nginx, you can do anything you want with it. ffprobe, ffmpeg, rtmpdump. whatever. No I am not just randomly googling.

Comment: Actually you are right. I think I can make it so that it just plainly forwards the rtmp that requests it. So then I can just subscribe to the RTMP anywhere. Then I can use any tool I want. Don't need to deal with low level stuff that way. For your very first comment, say, i were to able to save the RTMP stream to a 10 seconds flv video. do you know how I can check out the "frame type value in the flv tag header"?

Comment: Stack over flow is not a conversational message board, Please open a new question.

Comment: This is all related to the same question. And a follow up to your suggestion - setting up a nginx rtmp server.

Comment: "Repeated" questions are not the same question. One post = one question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to set up a nginx-rtmp server according to the tutorial [here](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/how-to-set-up-your-own-private-rtmp-server-using-nginx.50/) to reflect the third party stream.

And then use ffprobe to get the key frames.

```
./ffprobe -select_streams v -show_frames -show_entries frame=pict_type -of csv rtmp://<server>/live/<stream-name> | grep -n I
```

This commandline will output an index, and then a frame which contains keyword "I". According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types), an "I" frame is basically the key frame.

Comment: This solves the issue at hand. If you guys have better solution please write them down instead of down voting.